# Retrofit @POST not applicable to type

Tags: android, retrofit

i tried to create simple service like this

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import com.dolphithronelab.siastar.response.AuthResponse;

public interface SIAStarService {
    @POST("auth");
    @FormUrlEncoded;
    Call<AuthResponse>login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

But my Android studio displaying error that said : @POST not applicable to type, how to deal with this?
this is my AuthResponse class
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

```
public class AuthResponse {
    @SerializedName("login")
    @Expose
    private Boolean login;
    @SerializedName("user")
    @Expose
    private User user;
    @SerializedName("pesan")
    @Expose
    private String pesan;
    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;

    public Boolean getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(Boolean login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPesan() {
        return pesan;
    }

    public void setPesan(String pesan) {
        this.pesan = pesan;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semicolons after your annotations

```
public interface SIAStarService {
    @POST("auth")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<AuthResponse>login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
}
```